# Cannot find resource in split apks of Android App Bundle

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-app-bundle

Our team use aab to delivery features, just like "Google-Cast" or "ffmpeg" e.g..
Yesterday we updated gms to newest version and get new crashes on firebase, we reproduced them by installed app in Google Play or built apks by bundletool.
They were about "string resourceNotFound". Here is the screenshot of error logs below:
[image: resourceNotFound]

This problem is usually found in the devices brands are MI or OPPO, and the Android Versions are 8/9/10.

This string is a value in Google-Cast SDK which was implemented by the dynamic feature
(`<string name="media_notification_channel_name">Cast</string>`), so we doubted this was a bug of Google-Cast newest version.

We reverted the changes of version update, crashes gone, but we still found similar warning logs of "resourceNotFound" (Warning is about another string). And it always happened when the second time we started our app after feature has been dynamic deliveried, the first time we used app to dynamic load features and everything is normal. And it is alright if we build apk instead of aab.

When we tried to use debug mode to see what are different between features was just deliveried and application restarted after that.

We found a weird appearance: the assets of context losed all dinamic features' resource, see the screenshot of debug info below:
[image: assets of context when features was deliveried]
[image: assets of context when app restart after features was deliveried]

We confused with this and have no idea to deal with it. Is there anyone faced this problem and has any suggestion to tell, I would be very thankful.